# How can I get rid of this error: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'mongoose'?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have build a NodeJS server with typescript. In that I have created dbConn.ts file and written the following line

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

and created another file with name userSchema.ts and written the following line

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
```

Now it's showing the red line on mongoose by saying

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'mongoose'.
dbConn.ts(3, 7): 'mongoose' was also declared here.

Can anybody say? How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Your files do not have static imports or exports, which makes TypeScript think that you are running this project (and all of its files) in an ambient context. Adding static imports and exports will make each file its own module (and effectively have its own scope).